# how to build an angular 2 application with npm into output directory, and prevent webpack or any bundling?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-cli

We have a software production line (SPL) and recently we updated our client platform to use Angular 2, but because of a lot of problems we couldn't go for TypeScript, so we had to migrated to ES5 version of Angular 2.

We're not very good at TypeScript and npm and stuff, so here we're stuck.

Say you've downloaded/purchased an admin template for Angular 2 (Material 2), and it's a very ordinary and routine Angular 2 application.

You can `npm install` to install dependencies and modules, and `npm start` to make it appear in the browser.

However, by `npm start` what happens is that npm builds everything (I don't know where it puts build's output) and bundles everything, and in the browser all we see is a 9MB of vendor.js and everything else is bundled. That's not what we want.

We want to be able to just compile/transpile TypeScript in this given template into the output folder, and disable bundling of webpack, or any other bundling mechansim.

What should we do?

This is the template that we've purchased:

https://themeforest.net/item/fury-angular-2-material-design-admin-template/19325966

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You mention that you aren't using Typescript, but then ask how to compile Typescript without npm.  Are you using Typescript or not using it?

Comment: for what it's worth, the template you linked says it is using Angular CLI --
 `Updated @angular/cli to 1.0.0-rc.1`.  I don't plan on buying a license for the file to see it's code structure, but it seems like you are trying to ask how to use files made for Angular CLI without using Angular CLI, which isn't realistic.

Comment: @Claies, we don't use TypeScript, and this template is written in TypeScript, and we want to compile it into JavaScript ES5, so that we can use it.

Comment: it will be ***difficult*** to make further changes to the app once it has had Angular CLI and webpack removed.... You haven't really said why you have an issue with TypeScript, but I think you will be re-writing a lot of this or any template like it to avoid TypeScript, and at that point, why did you buy a template in the first place?

Comment: Beside that is the fact that you need *some sort* of script manager for Angular2;  You can't just throw `<script>` tags on the page and call it a day.  Angular2 *used to use* SystemJs before it switched to webpack.

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is moving to TypeScript and resolve any errors you are having. Every developer I know (including the Angular team) use TypeScript for Angular development. So if you are having problems with it ... we should be able to help. Going any other way is just swimming upstream and against a strong current. :-)

Comment: @DeborahK, TypeScript for one project is awesome, but for a SPL (software production line), where you have special needs for many many applications and they should be written exactly the same technically, it's not efficient and we're not masters now. All those imports, all those dependency injections, all those file-system reusability across projects, and many more problems. We prefer to stick with the ES5, because we're talking about industry, not academy. We need to make money and business value so that everyone is happy. We don't have tests, we don't use package management. It's SPL.

Comment: @Claies, we don't have script manager, and things go well. We really don't need it. That's a wrong formula. That's more like a propaganda, than being the truth. We've created successful applications, very maintenable, very cheap to build, with good payments for developers, and lesser cost for stakeholders. Isn't that fabulous? We think *what we need*, not *what giants offer*.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I think you **entirely miss the point** of the question and the responses to it.  The OP isn't trying to "build what they need", they are trying to take a ***template*** that they purchased that **someone else wrote** and make it work differently, because they don't want to learn how the technologies used in the template actually work.  If they want to build a full complete solution for themselves then fine, but that isn't the goal they present here.